# SQLPLUS Script required in PHP to run query for Oracle

Tags: php, sqlplus

I am trying to connect to oracle database using SQLPLUS and php. I wrote scripts to connect. But how can i pass the SQL query to get it result in SQLPLUS?

```
<?php
system('sqlplus tadmin/tadmin//10.100.3.64:1521/timing',$out);
echo $out;
system('exit',$out);
echo $out;
echo 'I am done running now';
 ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: And just for the record: you understand all the potential security issues when you have frontend code directly interact with databases?